# Why do I get errors when building on Xcode Server, but it builds fine on my development machine?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, integration, bots

I implemented continuous integration for an iOS app using OS X Server and Xcode.  When I build and run from my development machine everything runs fine on simulators and devices.

Then, when I choose to 'Integrate' and run the bot on my Xcode Server it fails to build with error: 
`Opening import file for module 'Swift': Permission Denied`

How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem, @Sean, did you manage to solve this?

Comment: I did, but it has been a while. I can't remember the exact solution.  Make sure all your provisioning profiles are correct on your server machine and in the correct location.  The location that Xcode Server accesses is different from the location when just running through Xcode.